# C++ Multinomial distribution

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, probability, multinomial

I'm trying to code a multinomial algorithm that will basically apply a binomial distribution to each value of an input vector, knowing the values of all previous ones. It's aimed here to **generate a new population for multiple alleles** knowing the initial population.

To achieve this, I'm using this recursive algorithm :
[image: general formula] [image: recursive algorithm]

This is what my code looks like right now :

```
void RandomNumbers::multinomial(std::vector<unsigned int>& alleleNumbers) {

/*  In this function we need two different records of the size.
 *  We need the size from the old populations, ( N - n1 - ... - nA )
 *  and we also need the size from the newly created population,
 *  ( N - k1 - ... - kA ).
 *  In order to achieve such a task, we'll use the integer "temp" to store
 *  the value n1 before modifying it to k1 and so on.
 *
 *
 */
double totalSize = 0;

for(auto n : alleleNumbers) totalSize+=n;

double newTotalSize(totalSize);

std::cout<< newTotalSize;

for(size_t i = 0; i < alleleNumbers.size(); ++i){
    size_t temp = alleleNumbers[i];
    alleleNumbers[i] = binomial(newTotalSize,
                (alleleNumbers[i])/(totalSize));
    newTotalSize-= alleleNumbers[i];
    totalSize = temp;  
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure at all about this, and I was wondering if there was an already existing multinomial algorithm of that kind...

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no direct implementation of this in the standard library and since questions suggesting a library are off-topic here, have a look e.g. here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/382/looking-for-c-c-implementations-of-sampling-from-multinomial-and-dirichlet-dis

Comment: There is [std::discrete_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the GNU Scientific Library's [`gsl_ran_multinomial`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/The-Multinomial-Distribution.html) command.

The function is called as:

```
gsl_ran_multinomial (const gsl_rng * r, size_t K, unsigned int N, const double p[], unsigned int n[])
```

where `(n_1, n_2, ..., n_K)` are nonnegative integers with sum_{k=1}^K n_k = N, and `(p_1, p_2, ..., p_K)` is a probability distribution with `sum(p_i) = 1`. If the array `p[K]` is not normalized then its entries will be treated as weights and normalized appropriately. The arrays `n[]` and `p[]` must both be of length `K`.

The function implements the conditional binomial method from C.S. Davis's "The computer generation of multinomial random variates" (Comp. Stat. Data Anal. 16, 1993. [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016794739390115A)), so you could implement using that approach. Let me know if you need a copy of the paper.

Comment: Hey,Thank you for this amazing response, since then I installed GSL, however, I cannot seem to manage to compile with it, and I only get a "gsl_rng does not name a type"... I will try to fix my problem, but thanks a lot !